# Turning Excel project into Web app

Tags: excel, web-applications, prototype

I've created a proof of concept (PoC) to test on users for a project. The wookbook is made up of a number of worksheets - which refer to each other - with LOOKUPS throughout.

I want to share the PoC with a prospective user but don't want to share the full spreadsheet file and only want them to be able to add to certain fields to test functionality. They will add text to certain fields which will then refer to different parts of the spreadsheet and make calculations based on those inputs.

If I publish as a web app they will have full access to the formulas (my secret sauce) which I don't want.

Someone suggested Google sheets. I've tried importing to Google sheets and publishing there but none of the formulas port across and as such none of the buttons I've created work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Protect sheets, protect workbook - use a long password and send the file I would say rather than doing a webapp from an excel file.  You can protect your workbook in such a way that it won't be usable, but will be testable.  The newer versions of excel have good protection these day's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. First, click the select all arrow at the top left of your sheet, right-click somewhere on the sheet, click **Format Cells**, then **Protection**, and lock and hide everything. Now go to your sheet and click the individual cells you need unlocked for testing purposes (perhaps color them a different color as well). Now lock your sheet.

A word of warning, though. Worksheets can easily be unlocked by someone who knows the workaround (or someone willing to spend ten minutes on Google to find it). If possible, turn your formulas into UDFs (they're typically reusable that way too, so it's an added bonus), and then lock your code down. You can also convert them into an add-in, making them a bit more secure as well.

Ultimately, I don't believe a web app is a viable option if you don't have the skills or know-how to build one. Excel is extremely weak when it comes to protection, and if you're not willing to trust your consumer and/or not willing to make your formulas insanely complicated (to a point where they're near impossible to breakdown by anyone other than the creator), then you need to rethink some things.

Comment: Thanks. So, if Excel is inherently difficult to protect, would your advice be to start again in Google sheets and then turn that into a web app?

I've proved the concept on a couple of users but the next stage is to move from proof of concept to something that looks "real" and not just a spreadsheet with a bunch of formulas in it. If I've picked the wrong toolset, then so be it, I just wanted to use the skills available to me (Excel but minimal Frontend, Web or Backend experience for the record!)

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the cells that you want the users to be able to enter data into and then protect the entire book.  Enable "Lock project for viewing" to protect your code.  Make sure you use a good password that is 16 characters in length.

...